# How are type qualifiers ordered from more qualified to less qualified?

Tags: c

From C in a Nutshell:

> the compiler implicitly converts a pointer to a given type  T  into a
>   **more qualified** version of the type  T . If you want to convert a pointer into a pointer to a **less-qualified** type, you must use an
>   explicit type conversion.

The type qualifiers in C are `const`,  `volatile`, `restrict` and `_Atomic`. I was wondering how they are ordered from more qualified to less qualified?

If an object being one qualifier implies being another another, then I would see the first qualifier is more qualified than the second qualifier.  But I don't see that relation between the four.

Comment: I guess it is about number of qualifiers. For instance, type `const volatile T` is more qualified than `const T` or `volatile T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no hierarchy among the qualifiers, each qualifier specifies a property for the object it is applied to. *More qualified* means having more qualifiers and converting from *more qualified* to *less qualified* means stripping qualifiers from the type of the object.

`char` is less qualified than `const char` and `volatile char` which are both less qualified than `const volatile char`.

Answer (score 1):

Assume we have a function

```
 void foo(const char *str)
 {
    printf("%sn", str);
 }
```

we can now call it with a plain char *

```
 char *name = malloc(256);
 strcpy(name, "Fred");
 foo(name);
```

However if we've a less qualified function

```
void bar(char *str)
{
   printf("%s\n", str);
}

const char *name = "Fred";
bar(name); // error here.
bar((char *) name); // correct, but very bad form, bar should take
                    // a const
```